# How can I correlate a running instance of W3wp.exe to a particular web application?

Tags: iis, web-applications, windows-server-2012-r2, diagnostics

SQL Server Profiler is showing me the process Id for a particular database accessor.

Windows Task manager shows me that that process Id belongs to W3wp.exe.

How can I tie this back to the web application? (I have multiple web applications running on this server.)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe#inspecting-running-worker-processes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the iis manager worker process feature to check which process belongs to which application.it shows you all running worker processes and some basic info, including ProcessId.You can match that ProcessId to the Processes tab in Task Manager.

#### Option A - GUI

1. Open iis manager, select the server node.
2. Double click on the worker processes feature.

   [image]

   [image]

#### Option B - CLI

1. Another thing you could try is run below command.

   ```
   %windir%/system32/inetsrv/appcmd list wp
   ```
2. it will show the process with the application pool name:

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but I haven't seen a solution I generally use.

It will return a list :

```
w3wp#(instance number) = ProcID, APPPool Name
```

Please note that I am not a coder by trade and there may be more efficient ways. However, this does the trick for me in PowerShell:

```
$count = (Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'w3wp'}).count -1
$var = 1
$result=''

while ($var -le $count) {
$id = (Get-Counter "\Process(w3wp#$var)\ID Process").CounterSamples.CookedValue
$app = [regex]::match((Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $id").CommandLine, '"([^"]+)"').Groups[1].Value
write-host "w3wp#$var = $id, $app"
$result += "w3wp#$var = $id, $app`n"

$var += 1
}


$result
```

Comment: This code misses one of the processes. I've created a gist here https://gist.github.com/jamiegs/5e3869f26830d2faf4b1e81cdaaf1572 which fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

powershell solution

```
import-module webadministration
Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool\WorkerProcesses
```

Produces this output:

Process  State      Handles  Start Time
Id

---

17480    Running    638      8/9/2023 11:29:17 AM